# Drag and drop form elements

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to create form where users can custom create form questions.

[Here is a full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9kjw6-epdb5c?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html), but I have a problem when I DROP elements, in this way they don't stay in DROP zone.

If I try to set form elements in the array like bellow, then they are not rendered in HTML

```
formElements = [
        '<mat-form-field class="example-full-width"><input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi/></mat-form-field><br /><mat-form-field>',
        '<mat-label>Select an option</mat-label><mat-select><mat-option>None</mat-option><mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option><mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option><mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option></mat-select></mat-form-field>',
        '<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option"><mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button><mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button></mat-radio-group><mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>'
    ];
```

Please take a look at example

Comment: link with example not working

Comment: thnx, I edit question...now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts` declaration`questionnaire = [];` :

```
export class CdkDragDropConnectedSortingExample {
formElements = [];
questionnaire = []; ...
```

Then should work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thnx, but when I add this, and I drag and drop radio button, and in FORM div try to click on some options, they change it in FORM ELEMENTS div, and select box not working.... Do you kno whow to fix this? Thnx